# Killing ghost NULL console outputs?

Tags: r

edit: added full code

I made an S4 method for 'plot' that appears to be working, except it outputs some stray `NULL` to the console and I can't figure out where it's coming from. Here's the top level code:

```
print(plot(x = flux, y = 1, fastplot = TRUE, quietly = TRUE))
```

And the class:

```
flux <- setClass(
  # Set the class name
  "flux",
  slots = c(
     raw.data = "list",
     source.files = "character",
     data = "matrix",
     time = "POSIXct",
     datatype = "character",
     metadata = "data.frame"
  )
)
```

And the method:

```
setMethod("plot",
      signature(x = "flux"),
      function (x, y, ...) {
        CheckFluxObject(x)
        params <- LoadDefaults(flux = x)
        # Interpret 'plot' arguments
        par.restore <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
        on.exit(expr = par(par.restore), add = TRUE)
        arguments <- list(...)
        if (!("fastplot" %in% names(arguments))) {
          fastplot <- FALSE
        } else {
          fastplot <- arguments$fastplot
          arguments$fastplot <- NULL
        }
        if (!("quietly" %in% names(arguments))) {
          quietly <- FALSE
        } else {
          quietly <- arguments$quietly
          arguments$quietly <- NULL
        }
        par(ask=!(fastplot))
        if (!("ylab" %in% arguments)) {
          ylab <- params["units"]
        } else {
          ylab <- arguments$ylab
          arguments$ylab <- NULL
        }
        # Pull relevant 'flux' class object data
        data <- slot(x, "data")
        if (missing("y")) {
          y <- 1:ncol(data)
        } else {
          stopifnot(
            is.integer(y),
            all(y %in% 1:ncol(data))
          )
        }
        # Bulk function execution
        if (quietly == FALSE) {
          message("Plotting data traces:")
        }
        plot.obj <- plot.new()
        print("NULL is in the 'for' loop...")
        for (i in y){
          main <- colnames(data)[i]
          plot.obj <- plot(slot(x, "time"), data[, i], main = main,
                           xlab = "Time", ylab = ylab, unlist(arguments))
          print(plot.obj)
        }
        print("but is it also here??")
        # Clean-up and exit
        if (quietly == FALSE) {
          message("Done plotting.")
        }
        if (length(y) == 1) {
          invisible(plot.obj)
        }
        print("or here??")
        invisible(NULL)
      }
)
```

The output for that is:

```
[1] "NULL is in the 'for' loop..."
NULL
[1] "but is it also here??"
[1] "or here??"
NULL
```

If I throw in another `print("what about here??")` after the `invisible(NULL)`,
then it does this:

```
[1] "NULL is in the 'for' loop..."
NULL
[1] "but is it also here??"
[1] "or here??"
[1] "what about here??"
[1] "what about here??"
```

Is there some behavior of the function return or print commands that I'm not anticipating? The CheckFluxObject function just checks to make sure all the slots are filled.

Comment: As interesting as this question is, it would be better if you could make it 100% reproducible. Please read [mcve].

Comment: From the `print(plot.obj)`. I just tried in the console `z = plot(1:10,1:10)`, the plot was immediately created, while variable `z` was assigned `NULL`. So you are printing a variable that is `NULL`

Comment: OK, R. Schifini's comment helped me kill the first one - instead of `print(plot.obj)` I used `invisible(plot.obj)` and it still displayed the plot OK without the null. Now for the second one! I added all the code necessary, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave this here till a better answer pops up, if ever:

Apparently the `print` method for plot objects returns a `NULL`, and if you're trying to generate a plot within a function it seems like the best way to do that is using `invisible(plot.object)` or `invisible(plot(x, y, ...))`, NOT `print`.

I'm still not sure where the 2nd NULL is coming from...

edit: Found the second one! Just like the `print(plot.obj)` in the method itself, the `print` in the top-level code was throwing a `NULL`. Dropping all of the `print` commands killed all of the ghosts.